# finding how many times each term has repeated in each document in java lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I have about a thousand of lucene documents which I already indexed, and I wanna retrieve term frequency per document for all the terms in all documents, here's how I index things

```
        HashMap<Integer, String> documentList = getEachDocumentSeparated();
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        Directory index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(RESULT_ADDRESS));
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
        IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
        FieldType fieldType = new FieldType((TextField.TYPE_STORED));
        IndexOptions indexOptions = IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS;
        fieldType.setIndexOptions(indexOptions);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> pair : documentList.entrySet())
        {
        Document doc = new Document();
        Field bodyField = new Field("body", pair.getValue(), fieldType);
        doc.add(new StringField("id", pair.getKey(), Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(bodyField);
        w.addDocument(doc);
        }
```

I wanna achieve a vector like below for example

> sterm,1(5),2(10),330(2),500(1),1001(3)

meaning the `sterm` in document one has repeated 5 times, and also in document 2 it has been repeated 10 times and so on...

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#totalTermFreq-org.apache.lucene.index.Term- should be what you look for

Comment: @injecteer first of all, it requires a term to give, and second I want to have the frequency per each document, not frequency for all documents